# Remove the word 'Categories' from wp_list_categories

Tags: theme-development

I've got the following code: `wp_list_categories();`

It outputs all my categories, however, it makes them the child of a list element, called `CATEGORIES`.

So, I get an unordered list, like so:

```
CATEGORIES
* FASHION
* DAILY FASHION CANDY
* TRENDS
* BEAUTY
* ACCESSORIES
* CELEBRITIES
* LIFESTYLE
```

However, I only need:

```
* FASHION
* DAILY FASHION CANDY
* TRENDS
* BEAUTY
* ACCESSORIES
* CELEBRITIES
* LIFESTYLE
```

I'm sure I could remove/hide the word `CATEGORIES` with JS or CSS, but is there a way to prevent it being there in the first place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the parameters in the documentation of [**wp_list_categories()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) function.

You need to use this parameter:

> #### title_li
>
> *(string)* Set the title and style of the outer list item. Defaults to "Categories". If present but empty, the outer list item will not be displayed. See below for [**examples**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Display_or_Hide_the_List_Heading).

I think it's clear, you just need to pass this parameter as an empty string:

```
wp_list_categories('title_li=');
```

Comment: Thanks, the following works: `wp_list_categories('exclude=&title_li='); `

Comment: @tmyie, no problem. Note that the `exclude` parameter is not necesary. I added an example of function call that should work for you...